# How to get data from YUI sandbox

Tags: javascript, yui

I want to get data from within YUI sandbox and pass it to another function. For example, if I have something like:

```
YUI().use('node','stylesheet', function (Y)
{
    var sheet = Y.StyleSheet('#myStyle');
    // Some logic...
    var styleSheetText =  sheet.getCssText("h1");
});

console.log(styleSheetText); //still undefined
```

How to get o value **styleSheetText** right in console.log? I don't now if it is JavaScript problem or YUI problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is both. In JavaScript you cannot see the value of a variable outside of the function it is declared in.  If you declare styleSheetText within the callback function for YUI().use(), you cannot see its value outside of that callback function.

It is also a YUI issue.  The callback function to YUI().use() is going to execute asynchronously, that is, the time of execution is unpredictable but it will always be after that console.log() statement gets executed.  Thus, even if you made styleSheetText global to get around the variable visibility issue, it would still show undefined.

Usually, you put all your code within the callback function for YUI().use().  That would fix both problems.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I'm not sure what you mean by a callback function.

Comment: Any example for any YUI component would serve as an example.  The callback function is the one you provide as the last argument to YUI().use().  When there is a callback function it is usually a clear sign that the operation is asynchornous, basically, the function triggers an operation that can take some time to complete, thus the function is provided as a way to say "when you are done with what I asked, call me back", thus the name.

Comment: In a browser, you often start executing code in response to a window.onload event or something like that, that ensures everything in the DOM  is in place before the code tries to do something with it.  When you use YUI, the YUI().use() wrapper is one more condition you test before executing any of your code.  Thus, instead of wrapping just your call to Y.StyleSheet with the YUI().use() statement, wrap the whole of the code with the YUI().use(), just as you have it wrapped with a listener for window.onload.